# How can I convert an array into SUPoint3D structure of Vertices?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sketchup

I am getting an output as an Array of Points from one section of the program and I want to use those array of Points to create a face in Sketchup, using its C SDK. How can I convert the array into SUPoint3D?

Comment: "Array of Points" - from Ruby?

Comment: Array of Points from a C/c++ program. However, I got it working with help of separately declaring the .x, .y, .z variable of each SUPoint3D struct variable.

Comment: You could put that into an answer with a small code example and mark it as the solution. That would help other people coming over this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Code worked for me, *pretty trivial :P*

```
int a[10],b[10],c[10]; //Integer Arrays
SUPoint3D pts[10];       //SUPoint3D variables
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    pts[i].x=a[i];
    pts[i].y=b[i];
    pts[i].z=c[i];
}
```